# Add delay on each loop iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, setinterval

The overall goal of this is to achieve a typing-like animation for some text.
I'm looping through each letter of a string and adding it to the DOM with delays between each letter, using `setTimeout` within a FOR loop.

My HTML--

```
<h1 id="name">Hello World!</h1>
```

My Javascript--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var typeText = $("#name").html();
    var textLength = typeText.length;
    $("#name").empty();

    for(i=0;i<textLength;i++) {
        (function(i){
            console.log("first function being fired!");
            setTimeout(function(i){
                console.log("setTimeout function being fired!");
                console.log(i);
                var letter = typeText.substring(i,i+1);
                console.log(letter);
                $("#name").append(letter);
            },5000);
        })();
    }
});
```

I don't get any errors, but I am logged first with 12 accounts of "first function being fired!", a 5 second delay, then 12 accounts of this:

```
setTimeout function being fired<br />
undefined<br />
[line-break]
```

I think I'm missing a fundamental part of FOR loops, or don't completely understand how functions are handled within them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a value to your inner `i`s.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var typeText = $("#name").html();
    var textLength = typeText.length;
    $("#name").empty();

    for(i=0;i<textLength;i++) {
        (function(i){
            console.log("first function being fired!");
            setTimeout(function(){ // not necessary here
                console.log("setTimeout function being fired!");
                console.log(i);
                var letter = typeText.substring(i,i+1);
                console.log(letter);
                $("#name").append(letter);
            },5000);
        })(i); // pass here
    }
});
```

And if you want each to fire 5 seconds after the previous, instead of just waiting 5 seconds and doing all of them, you can set the timeout like that:

```
setTimeout(function(){
// ...
}, 5000 * i);
```

Comment: Ah! Silly me. I'm still getting the same logs though :\

Comment: I added a way to have them go 5 seconds after each other.

Comment: You're a miracle-worker! So, I don't think I understand why the iterations just go all 12 times at once. I thought that the iteration count would go up when the function is completed (after the 5-second delay). What principle am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The for loop runs all at once, so it sets all the timeouts to be 5 seconds from when it ran. Hence, they all run at the same time. By incrementing the delay, i push the later ones to be even later.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were looking for a behavior like this:

```js
function doLetter(totaltext, i) {
  console.log("function being fired on text",totaltext,"at position",i);
  var letter = totaltext.substring(i, i + 1);
  console.log(letter);
  $("#name").append(letter);
  if(i<totaltext.length-1){
    setTimeout(doLetter.bind(null,totaltext,i+1), 500);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var typeText = $("#name").html();
  $("#name").empty();
  doLetter(typeText,0);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p id="name">Hello World!</p>
</body>
```

The whole deal is not to run all the letter handlers at once. Run one, let it know the original text it's working on. Once it's done with its letter, it will set a timeout for the next letter. Mind the "bind" :)